# All my Project have been erased by Pycharm

Tags: django, github, pycharm

I develop a site with Django and PyCharm.

I just linked my project to a GitHub repository, pushed the git-ignore file to make a test, and then I closed the project, when I reopened the project, Pycharm started to make some initialization, and all my Django project has been destroyed... I tried to find some files with recuva, the only thing I founded was a xml file.

When I open the project, the github repository is not even linked anymore.
And in the right upper corner I can see one of my old html file : base.html. (see the capture).
I don't know what to do, please tell me we can do something.
This is multiple days of works who have vanished.

[image]

Comment: This is unfortunate to hear, did you ever actually push to GitHub? If so will it not be in your account?

Comment: Pycharm comes with an ***auto-save*** feature ***by default***, So I don't think this happened because of you did close the editor. Apart from that, it is hard to tell what you have to do to recover the files without knowing what you have done.

Comment: do you see the folder of your project in you local disk

Comment: I just pushed the .gitignore file

Comment: I can see the project folder yes

Comment: I there an auto-save folder Elsewhere than in the project itself ?
I can see a lot of file whit my project name on it in a "recentFilesTimeStamps.dat" folder in the PyCharm directory

Comment: I need to precise that the .idea is the only folder remain in the project, the .idea has vanished !

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. The Project was in the the recycle bin, I can assure you that it's the first think I have looked, and it wasn't there at the first time, and I can't explain why it was put there by the IDE.
What a panic !